# I want to save a users name

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am wanting to save a users name for an alarm skill I am making. Whenever the skill is launched, it asks for the users name. How would I save the name so when the alarm goes off it says "Good Morning! {Insert Name Here}"

Comment: Have you taken a look at DynamoDB (or some other store, but DynamoDB tends to be pretty easy to integrate)?

Comment: i've looked into it, could never get it to work, do you have a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create a custom slot for a user name (It will work without a custom slot as well but it would be good to add one). Then you can catch your slot value in the 'event' object (If you are using AWS Lambda to execute your code). If you are using an http end point then you will get slot values there. Please find sample code. First in Launch request (Not using AWS Alexa SDK),

```
if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
        context.succeed(buildResponse({
            speechText: "Please tell you name?",
            repromptText: "You can say for example, Vijay",
            endSession: false
        }));}
```

Then your Intent,

```js
if (request.intent.name === "YourIntent") {
      if (request.intent.slots.name !== undefined)
      var name = request.intent.slots.name.value;
//Build your response here by appending name
}
```

You sample utterance would be,

```
MyFortuneIntent {name}
```

where {name} would be your custom slot.